# data duplication problem at mall parking gate

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I'm creating a mysql database for vehicle license plates at parking gates. the problem is, I'm confused when, I want the plate not to be duplicated at the entry gate, but when the plate has been out, the plate can be re-recorded in the database. if I use UNIQUE then the number plate data that has entered will not be duplicated however, if he has left the gate and wants to come back in, the data will not be able to enter because it is already in the database.

Comment: So you have a transaction table which records entry/exist of vehicle IDs.  after it's recorded it check to see if it exists in the vehicle master table, if not add it if it does ignore it.  the plate it self is unique, not it's entry/exist into the parking gate.  now the vehicle/plate and date/time would be unique so you could have a composite index.. just depends on what the requirements are.

Comment: You really don't even need to make it that complicated .. Since the plate is unique, you can just add `checked_in`  field .. 0 for not -- 1 for checked in ..  If you needed to log the times and dates .. That's where you create a separated table that logs check in - check out times .. gate info about said check in etc etc .. No need for a "transient" table ..

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need to split the information into two different tables:

- Plates, which contains the list of unique vehicle plates, where the plate is set as `PRIMARY KEY`,
- Parking_Info, which contains parking gate information, where plate is set as `FOREIGN KEY` with respect to Plates.plate (here plate is not unique), and the status is a boolean that indicates whether the plate is in the park or not.

If you also need to track how many times and when the car has parked there, you can add a date and/or an event_id field.